# A tag for every supply voltage?

Tags: discussion

Recently a bunch of questions have been re-tagged with tags indicating the value of the supply voltage in whatever circuit is being discussed.

Is this really necessary?

Are circuits run on 9 V so much different from circuits run on 5 V that they should be distinguished by different tags? Are questions about "9 V" circuits so special that somebody might be searching for them specifically? And wouldn't get useful information from questions about 12 V circuits?

I propose to remove all the tags (`9 V`, `12 V`, `24 V`, `5 V`, `3.3 V`, etc etc) as not making a useful distinction about the posted questions.

Answer (score 9):

For analog circuits, the point about 9 Volt circuits not being significantly distinct from 12 Volt ones, sounds good.

The only voltages of merit, **if at all**, might be 3.3V_logic, 5V_logic and perhaps 1.8V_logic, since the problems, applicable parts, and solutions do vary significantly between these logic families.

Comment: also [tag:mains] and [tag:high-voltage], which have problems and solutions that are significantly different than 5V logic.